# Avoid Kotlin runtime/stdlib conflict with other plugins

Tags: java, plugins, kotlin

I'm developing a plugin for a platform written in Java. This requires me to bundle the Kotlin runtime and stdlib in my plugin's jar file, since the platform doesn't provide either.

The problem I'm facing is a potential conflict with other plugins that might also have the Kotlin runtime and stdlib bundled, resulting in a conflict.

One potential solution I thought of is bundling the runtime/stdlib under my own package, but I don't know if this is possible, or how I would go about doing it.

I am using Gradle to compile the plugin, so any solution provided will have to work with that. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does your platform not create a separate classloaders for each plugin? For example, an IDEA, eclipse or NetBeans plugin can bundle its own Kotlin version without conflicting with the Kotlin versions of other plugins.

Comment: That's something I hadn't thought of, and looking into it, it does appear that separate classloaders are used for each plugin. I'll have to do some testing to be sure, but thanks for the info!